# Do modules run multiple times upon import in a Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

It is well known that even if a module is `import`ed multiple times in a JavaScript program, it only runs once (for the first `import`).

[Relevant aritcle](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-module-import-twice/):

> The rules are quite simple: the same module is evaluated only once, in
> other words, the module-level scope is executed just once. If the
> module, once evaluated, is imported again, it's second evaluation is
> skipped and the resolved already exports are used.

Which is why code written above a React component only runs once, as [confirmed in the docs](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#not-an-effect-initializing-the-application):

> Some logic should only run once when the application starts. You can
> put it outside your components...this guarantees that such logic only
> runs once after the browser loads the page.

My question is related to Next.js on Vercel:

Would `import`s only run once when the site is built, and never again?

Or does it differ between static and dynamic routes (pages)? I.e. a page, if static, only runs an import upon build, whereas a dynamic route runs the import every time a browser visits the page?

Comment: Share code, to understand your question better

Comment: You should be able to test this easily: a `console.log()` somewhere in the outer scope of a module will run when the module code runs.

Comment: You can just console.log() somewhere in outer scope of a module

Comment: @Pointy True, but I would like to understand *why* it does what it does, i.e. *how* it works. This touches on Vercel architecture, React server vs client components, Next.js dynamic vs static routes, and potentially more...

Comment: Be careful with the assumption that Ecmascript Modules _"only runs once"_. Ecmascript Modules are a **live binding**. They remain active for the duration, capable of communication back and forth, and the ability to change variable values, between the export and import scripts, until the script is terminated. React MUST run the script in the browser using DOM methods, so _"this guarantees that such logic only runs once after the browser loads the page"_ needs to be read with a grain of salt when Ecmascript Modules are involved.

Comment: Is'nt there information in Google?, did you researched?

Comment: It has to do with the lifecycle of a particular realm. For example, in a plain browser window, each page load is a completely new realm, so all the code involved has to run again, even if the previous page used all the same modules.

Comment: @DanielHakobyan I did, they (the Vercel / Next teams) seem to keep the inner workings somewhat close to their chest. I have linked in generic info available on the web re. module lifecycles.

Comment: _"this guarantees that such logic only runs once after the browser loads the page."_ That is basically impossible to guarantee. There's nothing stopping a module exported from continuing to run - and update the `export`ed variables after the initial `import`.

Comment: @guest271314 I am not qualified to argue for or against, but the quote is directly from the React docs (see link).

Comment: @Magnus Documentations make all sorts of claims that may or may not be true. It is left to the programmer in the field to vet claims and implementations - in the field. Whatever React claims must be understood as within the scope of what the browser does re DOM and what Ecmascript does in the browser. React can't do anything the browser can't do, and can't restrict what the browser, DOM, or JavaScript can do, either. Open up DevTools and observe the `console` here: Ecmascript Module live two-way bindings https://plnkr.co/plunk/mjBVQiRXgLCTbsSm.

Comment: @guest271314 That is not what is meant by a module running only once though. What the example does is to start a never ending loop in two modules. That is not the same as top-level code in modules running multiple times when imported multiple times. I am not able to think of a scenario where importing a module twice makes top-level declaration instantiations (ECMAScript reference) run more than once.

Comment: _"That is not the same as top-level code in modules running multiple times when imported multiple times."_ What do you mean by "running multiple times"? It all depends on what is in that exported Ecmascript module - which is essentially an unobservable box (similar to `eval()` and `new Function()`) if you didn't write the source code. There is no guarantee that the exported and imported module will even be the same source code between requests, because we can intercept and modify requests using a `ServiceWorker` in the browser, and server-side. What are you trying to determine and achieve?

Comment: Well, this is a bit of a tangent from the OP, but what I meant in my response to your example can be illustrated as follows: If you have a top-level var declaration in module A, and you import that module multiple times, that variable is never redeclared. Of course, if you put it in a never ending loop, or export a closure where you have access to the variable, then you can mutate it. But assuming you only have that one top-level declaration in module A, the evaluation of that declaration statement happens only once (the first time the module is imported).

Comment: @Magnus If you have one (1) `import` statement in one `<script type="module">` that `import` statement is hoisted and you are operating in strict mode, so you can't `import` that same variable in the same module multiple times without an error or exception being thrown. In general, yes. As long as you use static `import` with the identical URL. If you use dynamic `import()` and add anything to the URL, the module can  changed. E.g., we can make `data` be two different things in this case `const { data } = await import("./exports.js")`, `const { data: data1 } = await import("./exports.js?")`